# Часть речи "Сине"

Tags: части-речи

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться. Во фразе "Да разве там, где небо сине", сине - это прилагательное или наречие? Очень интересен мотивированный ответ. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему, в этом предложении -- в зависимости от интонации -- *"сине"*  может выступать и в роли определения к *небу*, и в роли сказуемого.

В первом случае *"сине"* -- усечённая форма от прилагательного *"синий",* которая может изменяться по числам и родам (жен. и ср.).

Во втором -- краткая форма от прилагательного *"синий",* согласуется с сущ.-подлежащим (ед. ч., ср. р.), обозначает признак грамматического предмета (небо *каково?* -- сине).

Может, в отличие от наречия, сочетаться со связкой:

*"Да разве там, где небо **стало** сине".*

Comment: Именно в этом предложении, невзирая на интонацию,"сине"только сказуемое, а определением оно может быть в таком, например:Сине небо потемнело. В роли определений краткие прилагат. выступают только во фразеологизмах и в устном народном творчестве.Но вопрос не о члене предложения, а о части речи,наречие(когда превращается в категорию состояния) тоже может быть сказуемым: тепло одет-на улице тепло, это не показатель отличия прилагат. от наречия. Показатель - вопрос.Каков предмет?-качество существительного.Как происходит действие?-признак действия.У нас качество существительного-прилагательное.

Comment: "Но вопрос не о члене предложения, а о части речи,наречие(когда превращается в категорию состояния)  тоже может быть сказуемым…"

Когда наречие превратилось в категорию состояния, оно именно так и стало называться: КАТЕГОРИЯ СОСТОЯНИЯ. А синтаксические признаки категории состояния -- это особь статья.

Comment: "Именно в этом предложении, невзирая на интонацию,"сине"только сказуемое..."

А в таком:

"Да разве там, где сине небо, где горы, где море"?

Comment: И здесь сказуемое, на что указывает неполнота предложения, эллипсис- пропуск сказуемого, вот если бы сказуемое присутствовало, тогда было бы определением.А насчёт категории состояния - некоторые лингвисты до сих пор её считают разновидностью наречия.

Answer (score 5):

Конечно, прилагательное. Обозначает признак предмета, зависит от существительного, в предложении является сказуемым. В сочетании "небо синее" Вы ведь не сомневаетесь, что синее - прилагательное? А здесь просто его краткая форма

Comment: Спасибо. Наверное, я некорректно задал вопрос. Фраза является частью стихотворения Эренбурга "Да разве могут дети юга" и по тексту "сине" используется, как сравнительная характеристика и отвечает на вопрос - как?
Не какое небо, в смысле "синее", а как небо там? Оно - сине.

Comment: Не "Как небо там?", а "Каково небо там?" - сине. Краткое прилагательное. А "как?" здесь не задашь. Вопрос к наречию должен быть от глагола, а у нас прилагательное, потому что определяет существительное НЕБО.

Comment: Да разве там, где небо сине
И не слиняет ни на час,
Где испокон веков поныне
Все то же лето тешит глаз.Всё в вопросе корректно и понятно. Это составное именное сказуемое, выраженное прилагательным в краткой форме, потому что вопрос "где небо каково?"

Answer (score 2):

В данных выше ответах наблюдается терминологическая путаница: смешиваются части речи и члены предложения. В вопросе интересуются, что за часть речи. Однозначно: это прилагательное (краткое), которое примыкает к существительному. Наречием оно было бы при глаголе.

Answer (score 1):

В современном языке краткие прилагательные выступают только в функции сказуемого, при этом согласуются в числе и падеже с подлежащим: вода холодна, тучи темны, небо сине.

Раньше краткие прилагательные склонялись по образцу сущ. ср. рода, что сохраняется в народной и поэтической речи: красна девица, добру молодцу, сине море, выйти из синя моря.

Answer (score 0):

Да, действительно. Это краткое прилагательное.
Фрагмент "где небо сине" является придаточной частью сложноподчиненного предложения. В ней грамматическая основа выражена существительным и прилагательным: небо сине.